# ¿Cómo puedo hacer dropdown dependiente en React?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

Tengo un problema para crear **dropdowns** dependientes. Tengo dos *dropdowns*: uno que tendría el nombre del país y el otro que me entregue sus ciudades.

El error que me aparece es

```
TypeError
_paisesData$find.ciudades.map is not a function
```

Mi arreglo es mas o menos así:

```
const paisesData = [
  {
    nombre: "Argentina",
    ciudad: "Buenos Aires"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Mexico",
    ciudad: "Ciudad de México"
  },
  {
    nombre: "Francia",
    ciudad: "Paris"
  }
];

const [{ pais, ciudad }, setData] = useState([]);

const paises = paisesData.map((pais) => (
  <option key={pais.nombre} value={pais.nombre}>
    {pais.nombre}
  </option>
));

const ciudades = paisesData.find(item => item.nombre === pais)?.ciudades.map((ciudad) => (
  <option key={ciudad} value={ciudad}>
    {ciudad}
  </option>
));
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de esta expresión `item.nombre === pais)?.ciudades.map...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segun tu estructura estás usando reactjs.

aquí te dejo el codigo de lo que buscas. y te dejo el enlace de un sandbox para que lo veas funcionando https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-select-by-other-select-xie5xd

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const paisesData = [
  {
    nombre: "Argentina",
    ciudad:  ["Buenos Aires", "Mar del Plata"]
  },
  {
    nombre: "Mexico",
    ciudad: ["Ciudad de México"]
  },
  {
    nombre: "Francia",
    ciudad: ["Paris"]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]),
    [pais, setPais] = useState(""),
    [ciudades, setCiudades] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // captura de datos de la db o local
    setData(paisesData);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    data.forEach((data) => {
      if (data.nombre === pais) {
        setCiudades(data.ciudades);
      }
    });
  }, [pais]);

  return (
    <>
      <select defaultValue="" onChange={(event) => setPais(event.target.value)}>
        <option disabled value="">
          --Seleccione un pais--
        </option>
        {data.map((data) => {
          return (
            <option key={data.nombre} value={data.nombre}>
              {data.nombre}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <select>
        <option>--Seleccione una ciudad--</option>
        {ciudades.length > 0 &&
          ciudades.map((nombre, key) => {
            return (
              <option key={key} value={nombre}>
                {nombre}
              </option>
            );
          })}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que estaba buscando. Una consulta, si en mi arreglo tengo algo así: {nombre: "Argentina", ciudad: "Buenos Aires"},{nombre: "Argentina", ciudad: "Mar del Plata"} Y en el dropdown no quiero que se vea dos veces Argentina, cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: @VanNought sería mejor que hagas un array de las ciudades, algo como esto

`
{
  nombre:"Argentina",
  ciudades:['Buenos Aires', 'Mar de plata','etc']
}
`

en un momento hago el cambio de mi codigo anterior para mostrarte el ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias, te pasaste, me sirvió mucho. El problema es que toda esa info me llega de una api, por eso quería saber si se podía transformar el array